# How to make InputField admit multiple entries

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, inputfield

Is there a way to make `InputField[]` compatible with `RepeatingElement` or a similar scheme of user interaction? The idea is to create an interface with many user defined variables, as many as the user sees fit to be exact.

Comment: Why not just several InputFields?  After all, how will you plan to segment (separate) individual variables during entry?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The question then would be how to enable the user to make the several `InputField`'s appear and disappear from the GUI panel with the click of a button.

Comment: Being able to add new input fields or buttons or any other elements is something that you can probably find among the Q&A here. You need a button to add the element, a button to remove it -- if you want that capability, and use of function such as `Table` and `With`. I think the advanced dynamics tutorial in the docs has examples as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something to start with:

```
multiInput // ClearAll
multiInput[Dynamic[list_], type_: Number, def_: 0, opts___] := 
 DynamicModule[{n = Length[list]},
  Column[{
    Button["+", AppendTo[list, def]; n++;],
    Dynamic[
     Grid[
      Table[{
          InputField[Dynamic[list[[#]]], type, opts],
          Button["-", n--; list = Delete[list, #]]
          } &@i, {i, n}]
      , Alignment -> {Left, Center}],
     TrackedSymbols :> {n}
     ]


    }, BaseStyle -> 
    ButtonBoxOptions -> {ImageSize -> All, FrameMargins -> 5, 
      ContentPadding -> False}]
  ]
```

```
l = {};
multiInput[Dynamic@l]
Dynamic@l
```

[image]